# Online leaderboard for my non-XBL WP7 XNA game

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xna, azure-storage

I want to host global leaderboard for my WP7 XNA game for people around the world. 
There's already a local leaderboard in the game, but I want to make it shareable, so anyone can see the top 10 scores and try to beat them,

My thought's till now is to have an Azure-based service to handle the leaderboard, or to host the leaderboard somewhere and update it through http requests.

I was wondering, is there's an easier way to do so? many games have done that easily, I'm beginning to think that MS offers that somewhere I don't know about (Beside XBL of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this, i hope it works for you.
and yeah there is something offered already but not MS.

[MOGADE](http://www.mogade.com/)

[nienderman.dk - some explanation about MOGADE](http://www.niedermann.dk/2011/07/28/MogadecomAnAmazingFreeLeaderboardService.aspx)